# What's the best way to get data from users you follow using firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

Let's say I'm following 10000 users and those users have 1 million followers. Now I want to get their contents.

Right now in my app on average users have 1000 followers, So what I am doing is, when a user post new content, I loop through all his followers and add them to their personalized section using cloud functions.

It works good right now. But what if someone has 1 million followers. What's the best ways to do it..

Function

```
exports.updateFollowersFeed = functions.database.ref("topics/all/{id}/username/")
    .onWrite(event => {
        var postid = event.params.id;
        var username = event.data.val();
        db.ref('topics/all').child(postid).once("value", function(topic) {

            db.ref("follows").child(username).child("followers").once("value", function(snap) {
                snap.forEach(function(follower) {
                    db.ref('topics/following').child(follower.key).child(postid).remove();
                });


            });


        });
    });
```

Database Example :

Post

[image: post]

Following Users

[image: followers]

Following Contents

[image]

Thanks :(

Comment: Please show the code and database structure that you're working with.  As you have it right now, we can only guess what's happening.

Comment: Just Edited the question @DougStevenson

Comment: You have a deeply database model.  While this makes sense to reduce the amount of space occupied by your data, it's making your queries very expensive.  With nosql data modeling, it's common to duplicate data and flatten the structure to suit the needs of the queries you perform.  So, to improve this, you should think about the most optimal query that suits your needs, then model your data around that.

Comment: @DougStevenson thanks for the reply. But in my case, to get posts from all users I follow (ex:10000). I don't think I can access them by any direct queries. So I have to manually copy all new posts to the author's follower's "following contents" database section using cloud functions(which can be 100, 10000 or 1 million followers). Then I will be able to access those data from a single node using available normal queries. So should I go with it? or are there any other faster ways? :(